# How do I pivot one DataFrame column to a truth table with columns based on another DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have one `df` with a `user_id` and a `category`. I'd like to transform this to a truth table for whether or not that user has at least one entry for that category. However, the final table should also include columns for all categories that appear in 'df_list', which may not appear at all in `df`.

Right now I create the truth table with a `groupby` + `size` and then check if any columns are missing, and then manually set those columns to `False`, but I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this in the initial `groupby` step.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1,1,1,2,2],
                 'category': ['A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'F']})
df_list = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']})

df_truth = df.groupby(['user_id', 'category']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).astype(bool)
#category     A      B      D      F
#user_id                            
#1         True   True   True  False
#2         True  False  False   True
```

To then get to the desired output I then do:

```
missing_vals = df_list.category.unique()[~pd.Series(df_list.category.unique()).isin(df_truth.columns)]
for element in missing_vals:
    df_truth.loc[:,element] = False
#category     A      B      D      F      C      E
#user_id                                          
#1         True   True   True  False  False  False
#2         True  False  False   True  False  False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
`crosstab`
I'd recommend converting that column to a categorical dtype. `crosstab`/`pivot` will then handle the rest.

```
i = df.user_id
j = pd.Categorical(df.category, categories=df_list.category)

pd.crosstab(i, j).astype(bool)

col_0       A      B      C      D      E      F
user_id                                         
1        True   True  False   True  False  False
2        True  False  False  False  False   True
```

---

**Option 2**
`unstack` + `reindex`
To fix your existing code, you can simplify the second step with `reindex`:

```
(df.groupby(['user_id', 'category'])
   .size()
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
   .reindex(df_list.category, axis=1, fill_value=0)
   .astype(bool)
)

category     A      B      C      D      E      F
user_id                                          
1         True   True  False   True  False  False
2         True  False  False  False  False   True
```

Comment: @ALollz You're welcome :) If order is important, you can add `ordered=True` as an extra param to `pd.Categorical`, this is useful when your labels aren't intrinsically ordered (for example, days of the week).